# FCM push notifications opens when returning to app instead of showing in the status bar in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

How can I make the notifications to show in the status bar instead of queuing up and received in the app when brought to the foreground?

I have set up the FCM-account with the APNs, enabled push notification, background fetch and remote notifications.

I've done the equivalent on android where it works as expected.

My message looks like this:

```
{
  "notification": {
    "body": "this is a body",
    "title": "this is a title", 
    "content_available": true
  }, 
  "priority": "high", 
  "data": {
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", 
    "id": "1", 
    "status": "done"
  }, 
  "to": "TOKEN"
}'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The notifications appear only when the app is not in foreground. If you want to display them when in foreground, you should implement your custom UI for this.

Comment: It is in the background.
Foreground works as expected. It's when the app is in the background it doesn't show any notifications.